# How to pass data as array of object in stencil js?

Tags: stenciljs

I have been trying to pass the data from index.html to table-data component but I'm getting it as undefined. Tried so many ways if I pass data inline in the table data tag its working but if I'm passing explicitly I'm getting undefined.

```
 index.html

       <table-data options="data"></table-data>

<script>
    var data = [ {name:'a', age: '25'}, {name:'b', age: '25'}, {name:'c', age: '25'}, {name:'d', age: '25'}];

</script>
```

table-data.tsx

```
@Component({
    tag: 'table-data',
    shadow: true
})

export class table-data{
    @Prop() options: string;
    @State() internalOptions: string[];

    componentWillLoad() {
        this.parseOptions();
    }

    @Watch('options')
    parseOptions() {
        if (this.options) {
            this.internalOptions = JSON.parse(this.options);
            console.log(this.internalOptions)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't pass "rich" data via html attributes. For that purpose you should use the `script` tag and assign the element's property like:

```
<table-data options="data"></table-data>

<script>
  const table = document.querySelector('table-data');
  table.options = [ {name:'a', age: '25'}, {name:'b', age: '25'}, {name:'c', age: '25'}, {name:'d', age: '25'}];
</script>
```

You can use string values for attributes as well, but you'll need to `JSON.parse` them later.

Comment: You can see an example [in the docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript#passing-object-props-from-a-non-jsx-element)